# Powerpoint Dashed Line appears solid in slideshow

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

quick powerpoint question. I have a chart, made in excel, pasted into the powerpoint. I have a dash line overlaid on a solid line. When I go to slideshow mode, they both appear solid. Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks for any help/tips!

Comment: The looks of a dashed line normally depends on the resolution of the display. If the resolution is too low to define the spaces between dashes, then your line will look solid. Change your dashed line to one with more space between dashes and it should look as expected.

Comment: How do you do that? I dont see a way to customize in PPT?

Comment: Is the dotted line from PowerPoint or from Excel? What version of PowerPoint are you using?

Comment: I've tried with it both ways and I'm using 2016

Comment: This bug still remains in Powerpoint, even 6 years after this question was asked (2023)!

Answer (score 0):

In both programs there is so-much you can do. There is only a limited list of dotted lines to chose, that is:

[image: dots]

Of course, if changing the dotted pattern you still can't get the desired effect, a combination of dots and weight should do the trick.

Only the trial-error method will give you the result you need.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I have already tried this - the size, weight, color, etc dont have any effect - it always appears as a solid line rather than dashed/dotted.

Comment: What is your screen or projector resolution?

Comment: its currently set @ 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem and found a workaround:

To begin with - the problem originates from too dense data.
If you have hundreds of data points for one line, this will make the line appear solid since it seems that at every data point the dash-space-dash pattern starts with a new dash.

That being said, my workaround is using trend lines. Trend lines don't have underlying data points, but steady functions and therefore don't exhibit this problem.
If no function fits your data, the moving average of 2 points should do the trick.